# how to open Tweet Sheet from hybrid app?

Tags: ios, ipad, twitter-bootstrap, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I want to have the functionality of tweeting some links/text from my Sencha Touch hybrid app just like what is shown in this tutorial(not leaving current app, tweeting from popup):

http://www.raywenderlich.com/21558/beginning-twitter-tutorial-updated-for-ios-6

is this possible from hybrid app? Can someone show me some code or point me to a tutorial where this is explained? I would prefer non phonegap solution but if there is no other way out please suggest me how to do this using phonegap because I don't know much about it.

One way which I have tried is using Twitter's URL scheme like this

```
twitter://post?message=SomeText
```

but this opens up whole twitter app and my app get closed.

Answer (score 1):

Use this url for sharing in twitter:

```
var url = http://www.twitter.com/share?text=your text goes here
```

If you are using Phonegap, then probably with phonegap 2.3 they added inAppBrowser option and you just need to open the url in window.open() function.

```
window.open(url, '_blank');
```

Refer this [link](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.5.0/cordova_inappbrowser_inappbrowser.md.html) for inAppBrowser doc.

Comment: If we open it in AppBrowser it will not use current logged in user in installed Twitter app, isn't it?

Comment: I tested it with Facebook share and it opened the installed app, not in browser. So, I suppose it checks and automatically opens the installed app.

Comment: I have managed to authenticate and tweet using inAppBrowser but when i use `window.plugins.childBrowser.showWebPage('http://www.twitter.com/share?text=message');` it open up a childbrowser window not twitter app. Are you sure it opens up twitter app for you?